# PYTHON3 - How to use List Comprehension with a numpy array, to unpack a tuple of Lists, to avoid running for loop multiple times

Tags: arrays, numpy, machine-learning, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

## In Short ->

How to write this expression correctly?? ->

```py
[(self._mean,self._var,self._priors)] = [ ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]) for c in self.classes]
```

## A Minimal Reproducable Example of this problem is , to generate the same error is :

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


X,y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000,n_classes = 2, n_features=10,random_state= 1234)

Classes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[[_mean, _var]] = [[ (np.mean(X[i%10==c]),np.var(X[i%10==c])) for c in Classes ] for i in range(len(X)) ]

print(_mean)
print(_var)
```

with the error stack as :

```
 /bin/python3 "/home/vivek/Documents/GitHub/ML-Coding-Playground/LecturesSeries1/Lecture 5 - Naive Bayes/CodeSample.py"                                             ─╯
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3474: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:189: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3757: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  return _methods._var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:222: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  arrmean = um.true_divide(arrmean, div, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe',
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:256: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vivek/Documents/GitHub/ML-Coding-Playground/LecturesSeries1/Lecture 5 - Naive Bayes/CodeSample.py", line 12, in <module>
    [[_mean, _var]] = [[ (np.mean(X[i%10==c]),np.var(X[i%10==c])) for c in Classes ] for i in range(len(X)) ]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

## Context for the Line of code :

I am running a naive bayesian classifier from scratch, and have written the following script to run my code :

```py
#script.py
#
#
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

from NaiveBayes import *

def accuracy (y_true, y_pred):
    accuracy=np.sum(y_true==y_pred)/len(y_true)
    return accuracy

X,y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000,n_classes = 2, n_features=10,random_state= 1234)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=69420)

nb=NaiveBayes()
nb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=nb.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:",accuracy(y_test,y_pred))
print(  "Confusion Matrix:")
print(  np.array([[np.sum(y_test==0),np.sum(y_test==1)],[np.sum(y_pred==0),np.sum(y_pred==1)]]))
```

I have made a few attempts at the code for my naive bayes classifier,

1. With use of for loop (working)

```py
#NaiveBayes.py
#
#
import numpy as np
class NaiveBayes:
    def fit(self,X,y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        self.classes = np.unique(y)
        n_classes = len(self.classes)

        #init mean , var, priors
        self._mean = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._var = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._priors = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float64)

        for c in self.classes:
            X_c = X[y==c]
            self._mean[c] = X_c.mean(axis=0)
            self._var[c] = X_c.var(axis=0)
            self._priors[c] = X_c.shape[0] / n_samples

        #trying to use list comprehenstion to remove the loop
        # self._mean = [X[y==c].mean(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._var= [X[y==c].var(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._priors= [X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples for c in self.classes]

        # Trying to have only one command for all three
        print([c for c in self.classes]) #debugging
        # [(self._mean,self._var,self._priors)] = [ ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]) for c in self.classes]
        # (self._mean,self._var,self._priors) = ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ] for c in self.classes ) 

        #debugging
        print(self._mean)
        print(self._var)
        print(self._priors)

    def predict(self,X):
        y_pred = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(y_pred)

    def _predict(self,x):
        posteriors = [self._posterior(x,c,idx) for (idx,c) in enumerate(self.classes)]
        return self.classes[np.argmax(posteriors)]

    def _posterior(self,x,c,idx):
        prior = np.log(self._priors[idx])
        likelihood = np.prod((self._likelihood)(idx,x))
        return prior + np.log(likelihood)

    def _likelihood(self,class_idx,x): # x is a single sample , c is the class, class_idx is the id of said class , and this returns the likelihood of the sample belonging to the class, given the mean and variance of the class, and the priors of the class , IE the probability of the sample belonging to the class as the __PDF__ of the class. It is the _pdf function from the video
        mean = self._mean[class_idx]
        var = self._var[class_idx]
        n_features = len(x)
        coeff = 1.0 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
        exp = np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * var))
        return coeff * exp
```

2. With use of three list comprehensions (working)

```py
#NaiveBayes.py
#
#
import numpy as np
class NaiveBayes:
    def fit(self,X,y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        self.classes = np.unique(y)
        n_classes = len(self.classes)

        #init mean , var, priors
        self._mean = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._var = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._priors = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float64)

        # for c in self.classes:
        #     X_c = X[y==c]
        #     self._mean[c] = X_c.mean(axis=0)
        #     self._var[c] = X_c.var(axis=0)
        #     self._priors[c] = X_c.shape[0] / n_samples

        #trying to use list comprehenstion to remove the loop
        self._mean = [X[y==c].mean(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        self._var= [X[y==c].var(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        self._priors= [X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples for c in self.classes]

        # Trying to have only one command for all three
        print([c for c in self.classes]) #debugging
        # [(self._mean,self._var,self._priors)] = [ ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]) for c in self.classes]
        # (self._mean,self._var,self._priors) = ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ] for c in self.classes ) 

        #debugging
        print(self._mean)
        print(self._var)
        print(self._priors)

    def predict(self,X):
        y_pred = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(y_pred)

    def _predict(self,x):
        posteriors = [self._posterior(x,c,idx) for (idx,c) in enumerate(self.classes)]
        return self.classes[np.argmax(posteriors)]

    def _posterior(self,x,c,idx):
        prior = np.log(self._priors[idx])
        likelihood = np.prod((self._likelihood)(idx,x))
        return prior + np.log(likelihood)

    def _likelihood(self,class_idx,x): # x is a single sample , c is the class, class_idx is the id of said class , and this returns the likelihood of the sample belonging to the class, given the mean and variance of the class, and the priors of the class , IE the probability of the sample belonging to the class as the __PDF__ of the class. It is the _pdf function from the video
        mean = self._mean[class_idx]
        var = self._var[class_idx]
        n_features = len(x)
        coeff = 1.0 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
        exp = np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * var))
        return coeff * exp
```

3. With use of one list comprehension, and numpy array manipulation ( not working), (error not understood)

```py
#NaiveBayes.py
#
#
import numpy as np
class NaiveBayes:
    def fit(self,X,y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        self.classes = np.unique(y)
        n_classes = len(self.classes)

        #init mean , var, priors
        self._mean = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._var = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._priors = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float64)

        # for c in self.classes:
        #     X_c = X[y==c]
        #     self._mean[c] = X_c.mean(axis=0)
        #     self._var[c] = X_c.var(axis=0)
        #     self._priors[c] = X_c.shape[0] / n_samples

        #trying to use list comprehenstion to remove the loop
        # self._mean = [X[y==c].mean(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._var= [X[y==c].var(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._priors= [X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples for c in self.classes]

        # Trying to have only one command for all three
        print([c for c in self.classes]) #debugging
        print(np.array([ [ np.array([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)]).flatten() , np.array([X[y==c].var(axis=0)]).flatten(), np.array ([X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]).flatten() ] for c in self.classes],dtype=object).flatten() )#debugging
        TempArray = np.array([ [ np.array([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)]).flatten() , np.array([X[y==c].var(axis=0)]).flatten(), np.array ([X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]).flatten() ] for c in self.classes]).flatten()

        self._mean=TempArray[0]
        self._var=TempArray[1]
        self._priors = TempArray[2] 
        # [(self._mean,self._var,self._priors)] = [ ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]) for c in self.classes]
        # (self._mean,self._var,self._priors) = ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ] for c in self.classes ) 

        #debugging
        print(self._mean)
        print(self._var)
        print(self._priors)

    def predict(self,X):
        y_pred = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(y_pred)

    def _predict(self,x):
        posteriors = [self._posterior(x,c,idx) for (idx,c) in enumerate(self.classes)]
        return self.classes[np.argmax(posteriors)]

    def _posterior(self,x,c,idx):
        prior = np.log(self._priors[idx])
        likelihood = np.prod((self._likelihood)(idx,x))
        return prior + np.log(likelihood)

    def _likelihood(self,class_idx,x): # x is a single sample , c is the class, class_idx is the id of said class , and this returns the likelihood of the sample belonging to the class, given the mean and variance of the class, and the priors of the class , IE the probability of the sample belonging to the class as the __PDF__ of the class. It is the _pdf function from the video
        mean = self._mean[class_idx]
        var = self._var[class_idx]
        n_features = len(x)
        coeff = 1.0 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
        exp = np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * var))
        return coeff * exp
```

and the one that I have an error in :

4. With use of one list comprehension and Iterable unpacking ( Error : `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)`

`line 33`

```py
#NaiveBayes.py
#
#
import numpy as np
class NaiveBayes:
    def fit(self,X,y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        self.classes = np.unique(y)
        n_classes = len(self.classes)

        #init mean , var, priors
        self._mean = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._var = np.zeros((n_classes,n_features), dtype=np.float64)
        self._priors = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float64)

        # for c in self.classes:
        #     X_c = X[y==c]
        #     self._mean[c] = X_c.mean(axis=0)
        #     self._var[c] = X_c.var(axis=0)
        #     self._priors[c] = X_c.shape[0] / n_samples

        #trying to use list comprehenstion to remove the loop
        # self._mean = [X[y==c].mean(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._var= [X[y==c].var(axis=0) for c in self.classes]
        # self._priors= [X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples for c in self.classes]

        # Trying to have only one command for all three
        print([c for c in self.classes]) #debugging
        # print(np.array([ [ np.array([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)]).flatten() , np.array([X[y==c].var(axis=0)]).flatten(), np.array ([X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]).flatten() ] for c in self.classes],dtype=object).flatten() )#debugging
        # TempArray = np.array([ [ np.array([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)]).flatten() , np.array([X[y==c].var(axis=0)]).flatten(), np.array ([X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]).flatten() ] for c in self.classes]).flatten()

        # self._mean=TempArray[0]
        # self._var=TempArray[1]
        # self._priors = TempArray[2] 
        [(self._mean,self._var,self._priors)] = [ ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ]) for c in self.classes]
        # (self._mean,self._var,self._priors) = ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ] for c in self.classes ) 

        #debugging
        print(self._mean)
        print(self._var)
        print(self._priors)

    def predict(self,X):
        y_pred = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(y_pred)

    def _predict(self,x):
        posteriors = [self._posterior(x,c,idx) for (idx,c) in enumerate(self.classes)]
        return self.classes[np.argmax(posteriors)]

    def _posterior(self,x,c,idx):
        prior = np.log(self._priors[idx])
        likelihood = np.prod((self._likelihood)(idx,x))
        return prior + np.log(likelihood)

    def _likelihood(self,class_idx,x): # x is a single sample , c is the class, class_idx is the id of said class , and this returns the likelihood of the sample belonging to the class, given the mean and variance of the class, and the priors of the class , IE the probability of the sample belonging to the class as the __PDF__ of the class. It is the _pdf function from the video
        mean = self._mean[class_idx]
        var = self._var[class_idx]
        n_features = len(x)
        coeff = 1.0 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
        exp = np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * var))
        return coeff * exp
```

5. Other Failed attempts

```py
(self._mean,self._var,self._priors) = ([X[y==c].mean(axis=0)] , [X[y==c].var(axis=0)],[X[y==c].shape[0] / n_samples ] for c in self.classes )
```

was a failed attempt

Can You explain the correct way to do this, and why these other approaches of mine are largely failing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This is a very long question. If you can make [a small, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates your specific problem, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I have added a Minimal reproduction of the error in the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks Vivek; you can probably just delete the rest of the question.

Comment: list comprehension is not a big improvement over the regular loop.  You get the unpacking error because you haven't actually the examined the result.  You are just guessing as to what a comprehension like `[(i,2*i) for i in range(5)]` produces.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what a list comprehension that does 2 things in the body produces:

```
In [122]: alist = [(i,i*2) for i in range(3)]

In [123]: alist
Out[123]: [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

That's one list with 3 items.  I cannot unpack that into two lists.

List comprehension is streamlined way of writing a loop with an append:

```
In [125]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:     alist.append((i,2*i))
     ...: alist
Out[125]: [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

The loop you are trying to rewrite does several things in the body:

```
        for c in self.classes:
            X_c = X[y==c]
            self._mean[c] = X_c.mean(axis=0)
            self._var[c] = X_c.var(axis=0)
            self._priors[c] = X_c.shape[0] / n_samples
```

You manange to rewrite it as 3 list comprehensions, but that doesn't save time - that's 3 iterations instead of one.  And as the above example shows, you can't unpack a single comprehension into 3.

Well there is a way - apply a list version of transpose to the list:

```
In [126]: list(zip(*alist))
Out[126]: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 4)]
```

Using whole-array computations as suggested the other answer is better, but I thought you needed a basic look at list comprehensions as well.

Unpacking can make nice compact code, but it is quite unforgiving when it comes to matching values

The 2 element list in 126 can be unpacked to 2 variables:

```
In [127]: a,b = Out[126]
In [128]: [a,b] = Out[126]  # or (a,b)=  all the same thing

In [129]: a
Out[129]: (0, 1, 2)
```

but you add a layer of []:

```
In [130]: [[a,b]] = Out[126]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [130], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 [[a,b]] = Out[126]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

This unpacking only works for:

```
In [133]: [[a,b]] = Out[123][1:2]

In [134]: Out[123][1:2]
Out[134]: [(1, 2)]
```

Note the same layers of nesting on both sides of the assignment.  That's important when unpacking.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It cleared a lot of basic doubts that I had with list comprehension in python. I will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to compute the mean and variance of each column in `X`. You can accomplish this without loops like so:

```
mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
var = np.var(X, axis=0)
```

In general, you rarely (almost never) need loops with NumPy. The `axis` argument tells NumPy to compute along rows or columns (as opposed to computing the statistics for the whole array).

(By the way, the columns of `X` are usually referred to as 'features'. Most people use the word 'classes' for the unique values of `y`, which are 0 and 1 in this example.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This tells me that I need to delve into the documentation of NumPy. I will do so now.